# How do I get a lone missing app to appear in Spotlight searches?

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, search

When I enter a string that matches part of the name of an application on Mac, the OS X [Spotlight](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18828?locale=en_US) search feature will suggest apps for me to launch. This works for *every* app *except* one: *Mathematica*:

[image]

While the string is recognized (presumably from my history) the application is *not* suggested, and the only way to launch it is directly from the Finder or some other awkward workaround.

Why would — indeed *how could* —  a single lone application behave differently in this regard? How can an application hide itself in this way from Spotlight?

And most importantly: *what can I do to restore this standard piece of functionality*?

---

Note that this problem is unique to *Mathematica*. For example for JetBrains apps, I get:

[image]

Moreover, it extends to the Finder itself. For example if I search there I get

[image]

even though *Mathematica* is clearly there

[image]

I can reproduce this (for *Mathematica* only) by simply updating (download, open the DMG, drag the new version to the Applications folder, replace). This is indeed unique to *Mathematica* (in my experience). I update at least one app a day in this or similar ways, and none of them vanish as a result from Spotlight; only *Mathematica*.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly exclude the app, _via drag and drop_, into System Preferences > Spotlight > Privacy and then close/reopen and remove the app.  Does it now appear in Spotlight?

Comment: @user3439894: Yes! That seems to work!

Comment: Not sure what caused the issue with that particular app however I was hoping that _flipping the bit_, so to speak, would allow it to be seen.  Let us know if it disappears again.

Comment: The problem has resurfaced following the "upgrade" to version 11.

Comment: The issue continues with 11.3.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

While this does not directly answer as to why that particular app does not appear in Spotlight, nonetheless as a workaround, try the following:

Explicitly exclude the App, *via drag and drop* from Finder, into System Preferences > Spotlight > Privacy, and then close/reopen Spotlight preferences and remove the App by selecting it, then click the minus button [-] at the bottom left of the list window.

The App should now appear in Spotlight, however it may disappear again if the root cause is triggered again.

Comment: This seems to work. I'll keep an eye on it and be back if the problem reappears (e.g., following an update of the app). How this occurred remains a mystery though (and how Wolfram managed to accomplish it when no other app in all the years I've used a Mac — and all the hundreds of apps I've used — has shown this odd behavior)!

Comment: The bug reappeared (again, uniquely to Mathematica) with the "upgrade" to version 11, and this fixed it again (for now).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, As I do not use Mathematica I'm unable troubleshoot the root cause of this issue. Lets hope that _flipping the bit_, so to speak, continues to work as a workaround until the root cause is determined and fixed on the developer's end. (That is of course assuming this issue isn't unique to your system and is a reproducible issue on other systems too.) :)

Comment: Seems like some app updates cause spotlight to not recognized the newer versions. This is a great easy fix though!

Comment: I've seen this issue recently with Slack and Radio Paradise (third-party App Store apps) on macOS 10.12.4. There seems to be a bug in the way App Store updates apps that triggers this failure to be indexed in Spotlight, but only sometimes. If this issue affects you, I strongly recommend sending a bug report to Apple via [their feedback form](https://www.apple.com/feedback/).

Comment: I had this issue with some of Apple's own apps, most noticeably keynote. This workaround is genius. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Worked for me with Skitch on macos 10.12.6. Thanks

Comment: Works for me. Microsoft OneNote always has this issue (oddly, the rest of Microsoft Office never does).

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue with Todoist and Microsoft Outlook. The answer above didn't solve the problem for me on MacOS Sierra 10.12.6, as you can only exclude whole folders now in the Spotlight Privacy tab. I tried that, but it didn't help. However a similar solution worked for me:

1. System Preferences > Spotlight > Search Results
2. Untick 'Applications'
3. Close the settings
4. System Preferences > Spotlight > Search Results
5. Tick 'Applications'

Comment: fwiw, this did not work for me but the accepted answer did.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Skitch disappeared and I can't get it back

Comment: `you can only exclude whole folders now in the Spotlight Privacy tab` Actually, by following along with user3439894's instructions, I found that dragging and dropping a single application still works, even though you can't add it that via the '+' button.

Answer (score 1):

For me the answer was, in the same fashion as the accepted answer, to exclude the entire harddrive and then re-eanble it.

As described here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7356551

*Note*: this is also the method recommended by Apple for rebuilding the Spotlight index, see support article here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716

Comment: This is also the official way to reset the Spotlight database.